# Should Task exception handling fail fast?

Tags: c#

I provide a method based on the TPL like:

```
    private Task AddItemAsync(Uri url, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (url == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("url");

        var result = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            // Do some stuff here
        }, token);
        return result;
    }
```

Now I am wondering if it is OK to throw the exception at once or to throw it within the task.StartNew {} stuff.

Comment: I'd say that if you don't need to do anything extra in `AddItemAsync` if an exception is thrown, then you can throw it in either place. If you do, then `catch` it in `AddItemAsync`, do some stuff in the catch, and then either `throw` the original exception or take some other action.

Answer (score 3):

Throwing it immediately is almost certainly the right approach. I'm sure somebody can think of some obscure reason not to--but based on your question it sounds like `url` is 100% required. In other words, if it wasn't **always** required then that may be a good reason not to throw it there.

But even then, I'd try and find a way to *know* I'm going to need it.

Throwing that exception on the background thread is going to be a hard row to hoe.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do processing if the argument is null (which is what looks like in your case) you are doing it correctly. You should have all the argument checks at the top. Why do unnecessary processing if it's not useful.

If you need to cleanup or something add a try/finally block and do the cleanup in finally block.

Answer (score 2):

Is entirely business rules specific. If you are adding tasks in a loop, failing in the loop will cancel the loop and some tasks (potentially OK) will not even be submitted. Failing in the task will actually submit all tasks and fail only those that had a problem.

If *all* tasks would hit the same URL then validating upfront make sense.